# Meteor and Jekyll

Tags: javascript, meteor, jekyll, octopress

I am wondering if it is possible to build a site with Meteor that using Jekyll to make my blog posts. Or even use Octopress and Meteor. How would I go about doing this, I am not sure if this is even possible having the Meteor server and the Jekyll server. I am basically trying to figure out the easiest way to blog using Meteor.

https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll

http://octopress.org/docs/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use jekyll without making a seperate server and stack, it would really increase your workload because you would have to communicate with the meteor server too. Jekyll is a ruby gem so I guess it would go best with a rails stack

You could have a look at a few github project at what look like Meteor blogs, they might be a good place to start:

- https://github.com/jefflam/meteor-blog
- https://github.com/xydudu/a-meteor-blog